# Filtering nested related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a fairly simple relationship with 3 models and having problems constructing a queryset that returns the results the way I need them.

Models:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class CategoryLabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryLabel)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, the queryset results should be a list of Books that a specific user has written a review about.

That's easily achievable by `books = Book.objects.filter(review__user=user)`

The tricky part is that I need to output (via django rest framework serializer) a list of books, each of which contains a list of reviews *only* for the specified user, aggregated average rating (again, only for the specified user) and a set of distinct labels the reviews were tagged with.

So something like this in JSON:

```json
[
    "name": "Book1",
    "reviews": [
        "review_id1", "review_id2"
    ],
    "average_rating": 3,
    "labels": [
        "label_id1", "label_id2"
    ]
]
```

What I've tried so far:

```py
Book.objects.filter(reviews__user=user)
            .annotate(average_rating=Avg("reviews__rating"))
            .annotate(labels=ArrayAgg("reviews__labels", distinct=True))
```

<s>This does produce the format I need but it aggregates average rating over *all* reviews, not only the ones by the `user` and the same story with labels, it just includes all labels applied in all reviews...</s>  EDIT: this is not true..

Any ideas how this can be achieved as efficiently as possible? Database is PostgreSQL so pg specific features are an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly, but the code from the original question actually does work. The problem I had was somewhere else, unrelated to this example... :/

There was an incorrect statement in the original question:

`This does produce the format I need but it aggregates average rating over all reviews, not only the ones by the user and the same story with labels, it just includes all labels applied in all reviews...`

Actually it does not so this does seem to work correctly:

```py
Book.objects.filter(reviews__user=user)
            .annotate(average_rating=Avg("reviews__rating"))
            .annotate(labels=ArrayAgg("reviews__labels", distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your models and your problem description, it sounds like you want group reviews by books having filtered reviews on a specific user:

```
Review.objects.filter(user=user).values('book__name').annotate(
    average_rating=Avg(F('rating'))
)

>>> <QuerySet [{'book__name': 'The ultimate code', 'average_rating': 7.0}]>
```

Sorry I've not tested with ArrayAgg, which is a postgresSQL specific aggregation function.

The code above was executed against a database containing 2 reviews one with a rating of 10 and other with 4.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, this looks like another approach that might do it although it becomes a bit cumbersome when I need to include other fields from the `Book` model... It seems my original code was actually working but I had another unrelated issue elsewhere that was confusing my test results... sigh...